# How can I get the corret date using the function strtotime in php?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I have this function in php:

```
private function setInfoTareasDiarias($aDataTarea,$idUsu,$seccion){ 

        print_r($aDataTarea['fecha']);
        $date=date("Y/m/d 00:00:00", strtotime($aDataTarea['fecha']));
        $aData['porcentaje']=$aDataTarea['porcentaje'];
        $aData['fecha_termino']=$date;
        $aData['descripcion']=$aDataTarea['descripcion'];
        $aData['id_tarea']=$aDataTarea["idTarea"];
        $aData['id_seccion']=$seccion;

        $this->aDatosInfoTareasDiarias[]=$aData;

        print_r($this->aDatosInfoTareasDiarias);
    }
```

`print_r($aDataTarea['fecha']);` print this format:

example: `2015/06/9`

With `$date=date("Y/m/d 00:00:00", strtotime($aDataTarea['fecha']));`

and

```
$aData['fecha_termino']=$date;
```

I need print :

> [fecha_termino] => 2015/06/09 00:00:00

But print:

> [fecha_termino] => 1969/12/31 00:00:00

(I need always 00:00:00)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify hours, minutes and seconds as H:i:s, like this:

```
$date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($aDataTarea['fecha'], mktime(0, 0, 0)));
```

The reason you are getting 1969/12/31 00:00:00 as the result is because this is the default unix timestamp, which basically means there is an error when you try to generate a date from your given timestamp. Try the H:i:s format shown above and this should work for you now.

Comment: Hi , thanks for you answer, but I need always 00:00:00 , and if I put H:i:s I have this 1969/12/31 21:00:00 yet for example..

Comment: echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime('yesterday',mktime(0, 0, 0))); Run that and see for yourself...

Comment: @PHPglue How can I do that? , sorry my english , If I replace H:i:s by 00:00:00 that part is ok, buy the principal problem is 1969/17/31

Comment: @OllyTenerife if I use date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($aDataTarea['fecha'],mktime(0, 0, 0)));  show this : 1969/12/31 21:00:00  :(

Comment: What is the value of $aDataTarea['fecha']? 2015/06/9? I have just tested and my result is 2015/06/09 00:00:00

Comment: @OllyTenerife I can change the date that I send in a calendar, for example I send now 29/06/2015 and print 1969/12/31 21:00:00 , but if i don't change the date in the calendar , and send the defect date ( 2015/06/09)  print 2015/06/09 00:00:00 I don't know what hapen :(

Comment: try this: $date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$aDataTarea['fecha']), mktime(0, 0, 0)));

Comment: De nada ;) espero que esta util